# how to make selecting a photo on an iPad look better using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the code below for the user to select an image from their photo library.
It works fine for the iPhone, but on the iPad, the user interface looks the same as on the iPhone. shouldn't it be different? How do i make it look like this...
[Image Link](https://www.google.com/search?q=uiactivity%20view%20controller&espv=2&biw=1517&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=VC5fVd_GGOrksATi94DABQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&dpr=0.9#tbm=isch&q=uipopovercontroller&imgrc=wX1GtHPNMh3HGM%253A%3BH8D_aEAkk9gyVM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.stack.imgur.com%252FcFZq7.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252Fquestions%252F11334062%252Fuiappearance-remove-custom-navbar-background-for-uipopovercontroller%3B736%3B488)

Here is my code...

```
import UIKit

class PostExperienceViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func segmentedControll(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        let segmentedControl = sender as UISegmentedControl

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0:
            //photo library
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {

                let imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)




            }


        case 1:
            //camera
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

                let imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)




            }


        default:
            break;

        }

    }




    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {


        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        self.ImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    }
```

Comment: The `UIImagePickerController` documentation instructs us that if picking a photo from library, one should use popover on iPad.

Comment: But how? what code do i use?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself...

```
 if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {

                let imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
                    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
                    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)//4
                    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as UISegmentedControl)

                    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
                    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
                }
}
```